# Too many programs spawned with Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I am using expect module for performing a task.

This is sample of my code

```
foreach temp $list {
    spawn -X $temp

    while {1} {
        expect {
            eof {break}
            "password {send "password\r"}
            "\]"      {send "exit\r"}
        }
    }
}
```

The script is getting break after 1071 counter. with the error

```
too many programs spawned? could not create pipe: too many file open
    while executing
"spawn ssh -X ..."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a relatively low limit on the number of simultaneous programs that can be spawned at once (it depends on how many virtual terminals your system supports; I'm actually surprised that you got to over 1000 there…) so you need reap those old programs once you're done with them (Expect does reap everything on exit, but here it matters because you're running out much sooner than that). What's more, the limit will depend on what else is going on on your system, as virtual terminals are actually a system-global resource…

To reap the old program once you're done with it, add `wait` to the end of your loop (assuming you don't want the subprocess to continue past the end of the loop, of course) to get this:

```
foreach temp $list {
    spawn -X $temp

    while {1} {
        expect {
            eof {break}
            "password" {send "password\r"}
            "\]"       {send "exit\r"}
        }
    }

    wait               ;#### <<<<<----- THIS!!!
}
```

You might also want to take a look at `exp_continue`, as that lets you rewrite to get rid of the explicit `while` (and also the need to explicitly handle the EOF condition) and overall make your code simpler:

```
foreach temp $list {
    spawn -X $temp

    expect {
        "password" {send "password\r"; exp_continue}
        "\]"       {send "exit\r"    ; exp_continue}
    }

    wait
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..But still i am facing the same problem. I also observed that spawn ssh is creating one file descriptor at location /dev/null/ which it is unable to close. As the max limit is 1024 ( checked with ulimit -a", so when it crosses that limit, throws the error "too many programs spawned? could not create pipe: too many file open
    while executing"

Comment: Fellow I hope the got the solution Simply add `code` close $spawn_id `code` after wait as suggested by donal

Comment: So my current code look like `code`foreach temp $list {
    spawn -X $temp

    while {1} {
        expect {
            eof {break}
            "password {send "password\r"}
            "\]"      {send "exit\r"}
        }
    } wait; catch {close $spawn_id} ;
}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a similar problem I am having.
Have you tried ulimit -a and checked either processes or files?